# Setting up Laravel 5.2.39 with AngularJS 2 RC 3

Tags: php, angularjs, laravel, model-view-controller, typescript

Please bear with me I am new to Laravel and Angular 2, and I now have 5 days trying to set up Laravel 5.2.39 with Angular 2 RC 3. I am only getting "Laravel 5" and "Loading..."

My package.json

```
{
  "name": "ang",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "tsc && concurrently \"npm run tsc:w\" \"npm run lite\" ",
    "lite": "lite-server",
    "postinstall": "typings install",
    "tsc": "tsc",
    "tsc:w": "tsc -w",
    "typings": "typings"
  },
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/common":  "2.0.0-rc.3",
    "@angular/compiler":  "2.0.0-rc.3",
    "@angular/core":  "2.0.0-rc.3",
    "@angular/forms": "0.1.1",
    "@angular/http":  "2.0.0-rc.3",
    "@angular/platform-browser":  "2.0.0-rc.3",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic":  "2.0.0-rc.3",
    "@angular/router":  "3.0.0-alpha.8",
    "@angular/router-deprecated":  "2.0.0-rc.2",
    "@angular/upgrade":  "2.0.0-rc.3",
    "systemjs": "0.19.27",
    "core-js": "^2.4.0",
    "reflect-metadata": "^0.1.3",
    "rxjs": "5.0.0-beta.6",
    "zone.js": "^0.6.12",
    "angular2-in-memory-web-api": "0.0.12",
    "bootstrap": "^3.3.6"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "concurrently": "^2.0.0",
    "lite-server": "^2.2.0",
    "typescript": "^1.8.10",
    "typings":"^1.0.4",
    "gulp": "^3.9.1",
    "laravel-elixir": "^5.0.0",
    "bootstrap-sass": "^3.0.0"
  }
}
```

My tsconfig.json

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "removeComments": false,
    "noImplicitAny": false
  }
}
```

My gulpfile.js

```
var elixir = require('laravel-elixir');

/*
 |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
 | Elixir Asset Management
 |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
 |
 | Elixir provides a clean, fluent API for defining some basic Gulp tasks
 | for your Laravel application. By default, we are compiling the Sass
 | file for our application, as well as publishing vendor resources.
 |
 */

elixir(function(mix) {
    mix.sass('app.scss');
    mix.copy('node_modules/**/*', './public/lib/');
});
```

My welcome.blade.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Angular 2 QuickStart</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    {{--<link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">--}}

    <style>
        html, body {
            height: 100%;
        }

        body {
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
            width: 100%;
            display: table;
            font-weight: 100;
            font-family: 'Lato';
        }

        .container {
            text-align: center;
            display: table-cell;
            vertical-align: middle;
        }

        .content {
            text-align: center;
            display: inline-block;
        }

        .title {
            font-size: 96px;
        }
    </style>
    <!-- 1. Load libraries -->
    <!-- Polyfill(s) for older browsers -->
    <script src="lib/core-js/client/shim.min.js"></script>
    <script src="lib/zone.js/dist/zone.js"></script>
    <script src="lib/reflect-metadata/Reflect.js"></script>
    <script src="lib/systemjs/dist/system.src.js"></script>
    <!-- 2. Configure SystemJS -->
    <script src="systemjs.config.js"></script>
    <script>
//        System.import('app').catch(function(err){ console.error(err); });
    </script>
</head>
<!-- 3. Display the application -->
<body>
<div class="container">
    <div class="content">
        <div class="title">Laravel 5</div>
    </div>
</div>
<my-app>Loading...</my-app>
<my-app></my-app>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What else do you expect to get if that's all your view has?

Comment: In the app.component.ts, there is a message "Hello Angular 2 World", which must be displayed

Answer (score 0):

For the help of others who may encounter the same situation, I finally managed to get it working though the help of this [repo](https://github.com/axiskafi/angular2-laravel5)